# Magento2.4 - Customer Login fails with "Access is not allowed"

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, customer-login

we get an error on "customer/account/loginPost/" with the message "Access is not allowed" after Customer wants to Login.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the controller execute function and debug the point at which it throws the exception/error.

Controller File -

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php

Quickest way to figure out the issue is to use xdebug and check the execute function of the controller. There can be some customization which throws that error message while validating the request and before calling the execute function. So, first check if the execute function is called and then debug it further.